# How does this awk script to delete blank and duplicate lines work?

Tags: awk

This `awk` command is used to delete blank and duplicate lines:

```
sort abc.log | awk 'LAST != $0 {print} {LAST=$0}'
```

I'd like to know how "LAST != $0" and "{LAST=$0}" are used and what do they do?

Comment: I has add exact need, and the confusion has been solved.

Answer (score 3):

The `sort` command sorts the lines of `abc.log`. The result is that duplicate lines follow each other.

`awk` take this sorted file as input. It compares the current line (which is in  `$0`) with the content of the variable `LAST`. Only if it is different (`!=`), the line is printed. The content of the current line is than stored in the variable `LAST`. So it can be compared in the next iteration.

NB: Instead of using this combination of `sort` and `awk`, just use `sort -u abc.log` to remove duplicate lines.

Comment: One small difference, alluded to in the Q: since awk vars are initialized to the empty string (also treated as numeric zero), the awk also deletes any empty lines (which `sort` puts first), but `sort -u` does not, although `sort -u | grep .` does.

Comment: thank you! this can explain how awk to delete duplicate records.

Comment: This solved my confusion.

Comment: Indeed, if the input includes empty lines and you `sort -r` and pipe to that `awk`, you get an empty line at the end of the output. If you just `sort`, you don't. It is probably worth editing your answer, adding the information from dave_thompson_085's comment.